# How to make a column a primary and foreign key at the same time?

Tags: android-room

I need to create a table with only one column that contains foreign keys. As `Room` forces me to also have a primary key, I want one column to be a primary and a foreign key at the same time. How can I do this? Further, does my primary/foreign key column has to be a `Long` or can it be `Item` and `Room` automatically picks it's primary key and stores it?

```
@Entity(tableName = "items")
data class Item (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var itemId: Long = 0L, 

    var itemName: String = ""
)

@Entity(tableName = "items_recent_searches")
data class ItemRecentSearches (

    // how to make this also a foreign key to Item?
    // further, is it possible to make this as type Item instead of itemId
    // and room then makes the conversion for me?
    @PrimaryKey
    var itemId: Long
)
```